# Include fail Zend Framework

Tags: include, zend-framework2

I´m very new with ZendF2. I installed and tryed to do the tutorial example from Zend website, but i´m stopped in some problems.

```
Warning: include(C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\module\Album/config/module.config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\Module.php on line 22

 Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\module\Album/config/module.config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\Module.php on line 22
```

I copied all steps, but i don´t know what happen. Noticed that the / are in different positions.

thank you.!

Comment: Does module.config.php exist?

Comment: Yes, there is. In Album/config/module.config.php

Comment: Thanks, you helped me found the error. The problem was that the file name was module.config only and not module.config.php. I changed the file name and everything is ok.